# D3.js JSON son with two fathers

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I use this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288 , to generate a collapsible Force Layout.

My problem is : I would like to plot a graph whose a son is linked to two fathers.

```
  father  father
     |     |
      \   /     
       son
```

There is a way to do that in my JSON file ? I can't invert my son by a father (and my fathers by two sons).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your current data file look like?

Comment: Something like that:

`{
  "name": "parent1",
  "name": "parent2",
  "children": [
   {
    "name" : "child"
   }
  ]
}`

Comment: Well, if you want to use the layout as it is, you have to convert your structure into the proper format at some point. You don't have to change the JSON, you can restructure it in JS once you parsed the data.

Comment: Yes but, D3.js don't recognise this kind of structure ; so if I have to modify how D3js parse the JSON ...

Comment: I think we have a terminology problem here. *JSON* is a textual data representation, like XML, YAML or CSV. You *parse* JSON into JavaScript objects and arrays with `JSON.parse`. This is the part where you don't have to change anything. Parsing JSON is always the same process. What you have to do  once it is parsed is *restructuring* the object so that D3 understands it, i.e. you have to write a procedure which converts your data to a new object (for example), like `var new_obj = {name: 'child', children: [{name: 'parent1'}, {name: 'parent2;}]};`.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. So I'm looking for modify the JS.

Comment: Your data object, yes. If you don't know how to iterate over an object/array or access its properties/elements, I recommend to have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196).

Answer (score 0):

I should use this layout : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 for doing that.